# named parameters are not supported JPA Firebird Stored procedure

Tags: java, sql, jpa

пытаюсь выполнить хранимую процедуру в "учебной" базе данных fireberd которая уже находится в examples, но получаю ошибку

```
 WARN : org.hibernate.procedure.internal.ProcedureCallImpl - HHH000456: Named parameters are used for a callable statement, but database metadata indicates named parameters are not supported.
Hibernate: {call ADD_EMP_PROJ(?,?)}
WARN : org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: 335544569, SQLState: 42000
ERROR: org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper - GDS Exception. 335544569. Dynamic SQL Error
SQL error code = -84
procedure ADD_EMP_PROJ does not return any values
At line 1, column 15
```

метод которым пытаюсь вызвать процедуру:

```
em.getTransaction().begin();
        StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = em.createStoredProcedureQuery("ADD_EMP_PROJ");
        // set parameters
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("EMP_NO", Integer.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("PROJ_ID", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        //storedProcedure.registerStoredProcedureParameter("unknown_emp_id", String.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
        storedProcedure.setParameter("EMP_NO", no);
        storedProcedure.setParameter("PROJ_ID", proj);
        // execute SP
       storedProcedure.execute();
        // get result

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
```

хранимая процедура **ADD_EMP_PROJ**

```
 create or alter procedure ADD_EMP_PROJ (
    EMP_NO smallint,
    PROJ_ID char(5))
as
BEGIN
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO employee_project (emp_no, proj_id) VALUES (:emp_no, :proj_id);
    WHEN SQLCODE -530 DO
        EXCEPTION unknown_emp_id;
    END
    SUSPEND;
END
```

Comment: обоснуйте необходимость применения данной процедуры.

Comment: кроме того, в ошибке явно сказано, почему она вызвана - вы неправильно оформили процедуру. "Названные параметры используются для хранимой процедуры, но метаданные базы данных указывает на то, названные параметры не поддерживаются."

Comment: необходимость применения - понять в процессе обучения как работать с хранимыми процедурами. База данных вместе с процедурами предоставляется с пакетом Firebird в качестве example как мануал, и я там ничего не делал и не менял. Лишь использую как тестовую для того что б научиться с помощью java работать с данной БД. Делал все по этумо мануалу http://dreamand.me/java/java-jee7-jpa-stored-procedure-example/. Данная процедура добавляет ID работника и имя проекта над которым он работает в таблицу "employee_project", которая связана с таблицей "Работники" и таблицей "Проекты"

Comment: необходимость применения - я о том, что то же самое делается и без хп. в любом случае в хп двоеточия не используются: `(:emp_no, :proj_id);` - это не синтаксис sql. вы тестировали эту хп в субд?